# Prestashop: Show the number of products on my wishlist header menu item

Tags: php, smarty, prestashop, prestashop-1.5, prestashop-1.6

How can I show the number of products from my wishlist header menu? This is how I want to look like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jDHB1.png):

I tried something like this:

```
<a href="/index.php?fc=module&module=blockwishlist&controller=mywishlist" 
title="{l s='My wishlists' mod='blockwishlist'}" 
rel="nofollow">{l s='Wishlist' mod='blockwishlist'} ({'wishlist'|count})
</a>
```

But it seems to count my wishlists and not my products from the wishlist.

Comment: Why my question have been downvoted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a quick solution for this problem. This is not 100% efficient but it will do the trick.

1. Go to **\modules\blockuserinfo** and edit **blockuserinfo.php**
2. Update **hookTop()** function to this (This will count the products from the active wishlist of the logged user and assign the value to *$count_products* variable) :

   public function hookTop($params)
       {
           if (!$this->active)
               return;

   ```
   $current_user = (int)$this->context->cookie->id_customer;

   $id_wishlist = Db::getInstance()->getValue("SELECT id_wishlist FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."wishlist` WHERE id_customer = '$current_user'");
   $count_products = Db::getInstance()->getValue("SELECT COUNT(id_wishlist_product) FROM `"._DB_PREFIX_."wishlist_product` WHERE id_wishlist = '$id_wishlist'");


   $this->smarty->assign(array(
       'current_user' => $count_products,
       'cart' => $this->context->cart,
       'cart_qties' => $this->context->cart->nbProducts(),
       'logged' => $this->context->customer->isLogged(),
       'customerName' => ($this->context->customer->logged ? $this->context->customer->firstname.' '.$this->context->customer->lastname : false),
       'firstName' => ($this->context->customer->logged ? $this->context->customer->firstname : false),
       'lastName' => ($this->context->customer->logged ? $this->context->customer->lastname : false),
       'order_process' => Configuration::get('PS_ORDER_PROCESS_TYPE') ? 'order-opc' : 'order'
   ));
   return $this->display(__FILE__, 'blockuserinfo.tpl');
   ```

   }
3. Now we have to display it on the menu. Edit **blockuserinfo.tpl**
   that it's in the same directory and add this:

   {l s='Wishlist' mod='blockwishlist'} ({$count_products})
4. Save all files. It should displayed in the frontend the number of products

*Note: If the user has multiple wishlists, the trick will work just for a wishlist

Answer (score 0):

It runs OK, but in "blockuserinfo.tpl" the variable is not $count_products, you must use $current_user. So, the good line to add is:

```
{l s='Wishlist' mod='blockwishlist'} ({$current_user})
```